# Why are power series not polynomials?

Tags: functions, polynomials, power-series

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series#Examples) says,

> One can view power series as being like "polynomials of infinite
>   degree," although power series are not polynomials.

Why not?

Comment: Because a polynomial only has finitely many non-zero coefficients by definition.

Comment: $e^x$ equals $\sum \frac{x^n}{n!}$. Is $e^x$ a polynomial?

Comment: All polynomials are power series but not vice versa.

Comment: @ÍgjøgnumMeg OK, I think I get it. A power series is logically equivalent to an 'infinite polynomial' (although the phrase 'infinite polynomial' is considered an oxymoron by convention) and a polynomial is a partial sum of a power series. Sound right?

Comment: @Somos Above comment also meant for you.

Comment: @Bernard I think ganeshie8's question is rhetorical and meant to answer my question.

Comment: @ganeshie8 The power series of $e^x$ looks like a polynomial to me, which is what motivated the question.

Comment: @mjc it is a polynomial if you take the partial sum

Comment: @ganeshi8 Thanks, I think we've got there.